# Influxdb retention policy is set but not working

Tags: influxdb, retention

I set a retention policy on a influx db, but it seems thats is not working. Old data is not actually deleted.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I expect to drop data older than 1 month.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. The logic is that the old data is still in the old retention policy "autogen". I just set "autogen" to 30d, not "0s" which is infinite and it worked. Basically when you set an retention policy in existing database, the new data is stored to that retention policy from now on. The old data is still stored in the old retention policy.